# Deploy an externally trained tensorflow model artefact

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I would like to host a tensorflow model (trained on my local PC) on Sagemaker and I followed this article: https://aws.amazon.com/fr/blogs/machine-learning/bring-your-own-pre-trained-mxnet-or-tensorflow-models-into-amazon-sagemaker/

However I'm not able to perform the inference. My model is an object detection model, locally it has generated frozen_inference_graph.pb, model.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001, model.ckpt.index and model.ckpt.meta, all this files have been converted into save_model.pb and variables.data-00000-of-00001, variable.index, then into .tar.gz by respecting the folder structure export/Servo/version/...

.tar.gz has been manually uploaded to s3 and I have successfully created an endpoint.

But when I try to perform inference, I have an error:
ModelError: An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: Received client error (415) from model with message "{"error": "Unsupported Media Type: Unknown"}"

My input datas are images. I need help.

Comment: the SageMaker TensorFlow experience was improved since this blog post was published, could you give a try with the latest approach https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/using_tf.html#deploy-tensorflow-serving-models ? It deploys TFServing in a SageMaker endpoint

Comment: by following this link, I think I perform exactly the same instruction of the section "Deploying directly from model artifacts", as I created my model artifact locally(in a .tar.gz) then uploaded to s3, the deployment in an endpoint is successfully done. My issue is when I call predit(), it returns an "Unsupported Media Type" error, whereas in case I train the model from Sagemaker the prediction goes well.  I have trained my object detection model locally on my laptop where inference expect a uint8, predict expects a bytearray

Comment: the server stack and pre-post processing scripts are not the same between the 2018 blog post and the link I shared. When you have an inference error can you go in the SageMaker endpoint detail page, and click on "logs" at the bottom of the endpoint detail page? this may contain more details on the actual errors